# JQuery Autocomplete suggestion retrieved from database

Tags: php, jquery

I need to to do autocomplete suggestion for my thesis and the data should be retrieved from database. here is my code but it doesn't work! this is my html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fetching saved records</title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="typeahead.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> </script>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input.city').typeahead({
                name: 'city',
                remote: 'samp5.php?query=%QUERY'
            });

        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        Enter the name to search data:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="city"
         autocomplete="off">
            <input type="submit" name="find" id="find" value="Find Data"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my php file.

```
    <?php
  include "connection.php";

  if(isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
   $query = $_REQUEST['query'];

    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT city, area FROM tbl_loc WHERE city LIKE '%{$query}%' OR area LIKE '%{$query}%'");
      $array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $array[] = array (
            'label' => $row['city'].', '.$row['area'],
            'value' => $row['city'],
        );
    }

    echo json_encode ($array);
}

  ?>
```

I don't know why it doesn't work cause there's no error in my codes.

[console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwWqj.png)

Comment: Have you checked the developer console? I see one big gigantic error in your "codes".

Comment: @JayBlanchard may i ask if what is developer console? im sorry im just a beginner.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You have to make sure that $query doesn't contain plain apostrophe characters.

Comment: press F12 in browser and check for console errors

Comment: That's not all @BlobbyBob. Apostophe's alone do not open the door for SQL injection.

Comment: @Bajongjong have you tried running the PHP script by itself?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero i already posted the screen shot of the console errors.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes i already did. and that was the result .

Comment: @Bajongjong chose tab in your print i can see only sources

Comment: @CaiqueRomero i already updated the photo above. can you look at it again. thank you

Comment: What was the results @Bajongjong? Have you checked your web server's error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard there's no error in my server's error logs. i don't know why it doesn't work..

Comment: You're not including a connection in `mysqli_query()` which requires 2 arguments. Your error reporting must not be on.

Answer (score 0):

[`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) requires 2 arguments, the connection and the query, i.e.:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT city, area FROM tbl_loc WHERE city LIKE '%{$query}%' OR area LIKE '%{$query}%'")
```

### Warning!

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

### You may want to...

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to your queries and other database operations. If not, you can typically find the issues in your current error logs.